# why does task manager show memory more than maximum heap memory for my simple hello world java application?

Tags: java, windows, max, taskmanager

I can see in `jconsole`, that my simple java `hello world` app takes 1 MB or 2 Mb, however in task manager it shows 12 MB. I need to understand it in order to analyze a problem in our java-native layer application which shows only 40 MB memory in `jconsole`, which we find normal and even on native layer there are not any memory intensive operations. In production environment, task manager shows 373 MB, which is much beyond our expectations.

Note: we don't have out of memory error yet, we rather have a watchdog service, which complains when memory goes beyond 250 MB and start logging it in a log file.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://karunsubramanian.com/uncategorized/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-between-windows-task-manager-memory-and-java-heap/#:%7E:text=Generally%20speaking%2C%20here%20is%20the,far%20as%20Windows%20is%20concerned.) might help you. The reason is that windows does not show only heap memory instead its overall memory of windows process. The jvm tools like jvisualvm or jconsole show the exact heap  space used by a java process